# Creating a macro in Excel that compares two columns, answers in third column

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't found an appropriate answer for this question and I'm very new to VBA, so I hope someone will help me out.

I'm trying to create a Sub in my macro that does a simple value compare between two columns, row by row. If they are an exact match it will populate a third column with "Yes", otherwise it will say "No"

All columns are within an excel Table and have the same amount of rows, an example of what the result should look like is this (don't have enough rep to post image):

[image]

I was thinking something like a For Each statement but I'm not sure how to create it the right way. Thank you ahead of time for your help!

Comment: Why not use a formula in the third column. That would be much less overhead. `if(A1=B1, "No", "Yes")`

Comment: I would, except earlier in my macro I wipe my table and resize it to 1 row, so that when a new sample is pasted in that table it refitted. In essence each time this thing runs, it compares a varying range and needs to accommodate for that variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input!
I took elements from your answers and managed to come up with a code that solves my problem. Let me know if you have any questions

```
Sub Compare

On Error Resume Next
Dim Sm_Row As Long

Sm_Row = Range("Table1[Same?]").Row

For Each cl In Range("Table1[Same?]")
    If Range("Table1[Col1]").Cells(Sm_Row, 1).Value = Range("Table1[Col2]").Cells(Sm_Row, 1).Value Then
        cl.Value = "Yes"
    Else
        cl.Value = "No"
    End If
        Sm_Row = Sm_Row + 1
Next cl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick subroutine to loop through rows 1 through 20 and compare results:

```
for i = 1 to 20
    If sheet1.range("A" & i).value = sheet1.Range("B" & i).value Then
        sheet1.Range("C" & i).value = "No"
    Else
        sheet1.Range("C" & i).value = "Yes"
    End if
Next i
```

Because this seems like more of a learning experiment, you can also reference cells by:

```
for i = 1 to 20
    If sheet1.cells(i,1).value = sheet1.cells(i,2).value Then
        sheet1.cells(i,3).value = "No"
    Else
        sheet1.cells(i,3).value = "Yes"
    End if
Next i
```

You mention the range will vary in size. You can get the last row that is populated and then loop from 1 to that with:

```
Dim endRow as long

endRow = Sheet1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row
for i = 1 to endRow
    If sheet1.range("A" & i).value = sheet1.Range("B" & i).value Then
        sheet1.Range("C" & i).value = "No"
    Else
        sheet1.Range("C" & i).value = "Yes"
    End if
Next i
```

Comment: This looks promising! Can the subroutine be written so that the rows it goes through isn't constant, but is dependent on the length of the table? i.e something like Range("Table1[Same?]")

Comment: Just added that a second ago! :)

Answer (score 0):

A table will automatically bring formulas to a new row when a new row is inserted. For instance, say you have the following table where the `Same?` column contains the formula `=IF(C3=D3, "Yes", "No")`

[image]

As you enter a new row in the table, the formula in the `Same?` column will be automatically brought to the new row. For example, this is what that cell will look like once I hit `Tab` to create a new row:

[image]

Now say you want to completely repopulate the table with a new set of data. That's no problem, simply copy the new data and paste it in the table like so:

**Copy**

[image]

**Paste into first cell**

[image]

The table takes care of the formulas for you, effectively making a macro unnecessary.